# Manage Environment Variables

Tags: python, go, environment-variables, virtualenv

I've previously used Python tools like `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` in Python projects, but now I'm working on a project in Go so I'd like a general tool to switch environment variables when I do something like

```
workon myproject
....
deactivate myproject
```

I especially like the workflow of `virtualenv-wrapper` with pre and post activation scripts in which I can `preactivate.sh`

```
export MYVAR=xxx
```

and postactivate

```
unset MYVAR
```

The tools I've mentioned seem to be centered around Python and pip, but since my project is in Go, I don't know if its kosher for me to use Python tools that happen to provide environment variable management features. Anything more general purpose you would suggest and is not hard to set up?

This question is not necessarily Go lang specific.

Comment: Setting and unsetting environment variables is OS specific and not language dependent.  Feel free to use the tools which originally were meant for Python also for Go.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I believe these tools are overkill. Just what I want could be done with bash scripts, but I'm sure someone must have implemented something to do this?

Comment: @fractalous Actually, you have just one variable to set ($GOPATH) in order to set up a different work space. Do you really need a tool for that?

Comment: I may want my project to read configuration values from environment variables. Each project of course has different configuration values. API secret keys are often stored in environment variables so they don't end up in source code for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can use gvm:

https://github.com/moovweb/gvm

If you've ever used rvm for ruby, it's similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [envirius (universal virtual environments manager)](https://github.com/ekalinin/envirius), which allows to compile any version of go and create any number of environments based on it. `$GOPATH`/`$GOROOT` are depend on each particular environment.

Moreover, it allows to create environments with mixed languages.

Here is and example of compiling go-based application with envirius:

```
$ nv mk go-hugo-test --go=1.2.1
Creating environment: go-hugo-test ...
 * installing go==1.2.1 ...
 * done (in 8 secs.)

$ nv ls 
Available environment(s):
go-hugo-test (go==1.2.1)

$ nv on go-hugo-test
(go-hugo-test) $ go get github.com/spf13/hugo
(go-hugo-test) $ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/spf13/hugo
(go-hugo-test) $ go build -o hugo main.go
(go-hugo-test) $ cd -
(go-hugo-test) $ hugo version
Hugo Static Site Generator v0.11-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If down the line, you're looking for something a little more platform-agnostic and lightweight, a great choice would be Biome. It provides a simple interface to define an environment that can be used to give anyone who clones the app a specified environment.

http://github.com/1egoman/biome

(Full disclosure: I'm the author)